# Activation filed(after publish )

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, itext

First I download crystal report, next iTextSharp and I cant use program after publish(activation problem). So I uninstal crystal report and iTextSharp and remove from solution but I still have problem with activation my own program... Download from OneDrive version prior to 2 days. Try bulish and have same problem. Please help me this program is my my diploma work that I must soon submit and i dont know waths going on :/

Here i past error code: http://pokazywarka.pl/weupxb/

I try delete all non original references and try publish with default manifest or without. But finally nothing changed.

Comment: I don't understand the question because I don't know how Crystal Reports and iTextSharp are related. Note that I'm the CEO of the company that sells iTextSharp licenses, so if Crystal Reports uses iTextSharp, I need to know.

Comment: First i try with crystal reports but i resigned and download itextsharps. Before i have also SQLlite. Simple i dont know where is the problem may in one of thes addons, meyby not(now i uinstall all and delete references). I can add my project for wiev

Comment: Now i try create new project wit only one empyty button and when i publish it and install i have same problem

Comment: You are adding more confusion to your already very unclear question. What is a project with only one empty button? What are you trying to achieve? I'm going to vote to close the question.

Comment: I tried to check whether the problem stems from the main project and setup or from the entire setup of  Visual Studio.

Comment: Well, if you set up Visual Studio and if you can't get a simple Hello World application to work, then you have a Visual Studio problem that is unrelated to iTextSharp, Crystal Reports, etc... In that case, you need to fix your Visual Studio installation.

Comment: This is 100% unrelated to iTextSharp or Crystal Reports. You are recieving a `E_ACCESSDENIED` exception upon deployment. Check out this thread for some possible solutions. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7dc4fab0-6689-4582-8869-51d8319ffa39/clickonce-exception

Comment: I forgot, I made this program on PC(W8.1) and I publish1 and try run publish1 at laptop(W8.1), after this I publish2 from laptop for laptop and publish2 have same error.